# Git - unable to add files to repo

Tags: git, github, git-add

I am new to Git and GitHub.

I have created a public repository username/test_files in Github.

On my local machine, I have created a similar folder `/users/username/test_files`
I created a new test.md file and saved it under `/test_files` on my local machine.
I then ran the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/test_files
git add .
git commit -m "New file has been added"
git push origin master
```

That doesn't push the file to GitHub.
I think the sequence of steps is correct. I did a `git status` after add and commit and it did show that it added the `test.md` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I resolved this. Looks like the remote contained work that I did not have locally. So I ran the following  git pull https://github.com/username/test_files and then git push origin master. Now the file was pushed to GitHub. Thanks for your help.